# Shipment API inserting instead of update

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to create a Shipment via the API (endpoint ver 17.200.001).  I first build JSON with minimal fields for an insert, which inserts correctly.  But then when I update the JSON with the new Shipment number, and other fields and child collections, it performs an insert instead of an update.

My API url is http://localhost/acuroyal172100034/entity/default/17.200.001/Shipment.  My insert JSON is:

```
{
    "CustomerID": {
        "value": "CVS HEALTH"
    },
    "LocationID": {
        "value": "MAIN"
    },
    "ShipmentDate": {
        "value": "2019-07-17T00:00:00-04:00"
    },
    "WarehouseID": {
        "value": "002"
    }
}
```

My update JSON is:

```
{
    "BaseCurrencyID": {
        "value": "USD"
    },
    "ControlQty": {
        "value": 1
    },
    "CreatedDateTime": {
        "value": "2019-07-17T15:22:45.953-04:00"
    },
    "CurrencyID": {
        "value": "USD"
    },
    "CurrencyRate": {
        "value": 1
    },
    "CurrencyViewState": {
        "value": false
    },
    "CustomerID": {
        "value": "CVS HEALTH"
    },
    "Details": [
        {
            "Description": {
                "value": "1833137 Body MM016997"
            },
            "FreeItem": {
                "value": false
            },
            "InventoryID": {
                "value": "0036920"
            },
            "LineNbr": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "LocationID": {
                "value": "01P"
            },
            "LotSerialNbr": {},
            "OpenQty": {
                "value": 0
            },
            "OrderedQty": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "OrderLineNbr": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "OrderNbr": {
                "value": "036241"
            },
            "OrderType": {
                "value": "SO"
            },
            "OriginalQty": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "ShippedQty": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "UOM": {
                "value": "EACH"
            },
            "WarehouseID": {
                "value": "002"
            }
        }
    ],
    "EffectiveDate": {
        "value": "2019-07-17T00:00:00-04:00"
    },
    "FreightAmount": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "FreightCost": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "FreightCurrency": {
        "value": "USD"
    },
    "GroundCollect": {
        "value": false
    },
    "Hold": {
        "value": false
    },
    "Insurance": {
        "value": true
    },
    "LastModifiedDateTime": {
        "value": "2019-07-17T15:23:31"
    },
    "LocationID": {
        "value": "MAIN"
    },
    "Operation": {
        "value": "Issue"
    },
    "Orders": [
        {
            "OrderNbr": {
                "value": "036241"
            },
            "OrderType": {
                "value": "SO"
            },
            "ShipmentNbr": {
                "value": "036971"
            },
            "ShipmentType": {
                "value": "Shipment"
            },
            "ShippedQty": {
                "value": 1
            },
            "ShippedVolume": {
                "value": 0
            },
            "ShippedWeight": {
                "value": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "PackageCount": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "PackageWeight": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "ReciprocalRate": {
        "value": 1
    },
    "ResidentialDelivery": {
        "value": false
    },
    "SaturdayDelivery": {
        "value": false
    },
    "ShipmentDate": {
        "value": "2019-07-17T00:00:00-04:00"
    },
    "ShipmentNbr": {
        "value": "036971"
    },
    "ShippedQty": {
        "value": 1
    },
    "ShippedVolume": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "ShippedWeight": {
        "value": 0
    },
    "ShippingSettings": {
        "ShipToAddress": {
            "Country": {
                "value": "US"
            }
        },
        "ShipToAddressOverride": {
            "value": false
        },
        "ShipToContact": {
            "BusinessName": {
                "value": "CVS HEALTH"
            }
        },
        "ShipToContactOverride": {
            "value": false
        }
    },
    "ShippingTerms": {
        "value": "3RD PARTY"
    },
    "Type": {
        "value": "Shipment"
    },
    "WarehouseID": {
        "value": "002"
    }
}
```

I first tried to put all of this in one API call to insert it all at once, but that gave some weird sequence error, so I was trying it this way because I have had to do this in the past as well with another endpoint.  How can I get the update to update instead of insert?

Comment: If you use existing     "ShipmentNbr" for your update call, it should work. Could you please double check that you use existing ShipmentNbr?

Comment: The issue I posted is no longer my issue.  I believe I have some threading issues going on currently with race conditions causing some of this.  I'll respond later if I have an update.